# Postgres: How to insert row with autoincrement id

Tags: postgresql, select, insert, auto-increment

There is a Table "context".
There is an autoincrement id "context_id".
I am using sequence to retrieve the next value.

```
SELECT nextval('context_context_id_seq')
```

The result is: 1, 2, 3,...20....

But there are 24780 rows in the "context" table

How can I get the next value (24781)?

I need to use it in the INSERT statement

Answer (score 35):

Apparently you inserted rows into that table *without* using the sequence and that's why they are out of sync.

You need to set the correct value for the sequence using `setval()`

```
select setval('context_context_id_seq', (select max(context_id) from context));
```

Then the next call to `nextval()` should return the correct value.

*If* the column is indeed defined as `serial` (there is no "auto increment" in Postgres) then you should let Postgres do it's job and never mention it during insers:

```
insert into context (some_column, some_other_column)
values (42, 'foobar');
```

will make sure the default value for the context_id column is applied. Alternatively you could use:

```
insert into context (context_id, some_column, some_other_column)
values (default, 42, 'foobar');
```

Comment: and when using serial count still can jump over 1 or 2 id's. That because postgresql first takes nextval then tries to insert and if it fails for somereason that id is already used

Comment: @user503207: a sequence is **never** guaranteed to be gap-free.

Comment: Autoincrement fields, sequences, serials, identity whatever you want to call them, generally have a caching mechanism which means that strictly linear gap-free monotonically increasing sequences of integers are impossible to guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO public.tablename (id, operator, text) values((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM public.tablename), 'OPERATOR','');
```

Comment: [why is this the correct answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is bad practice